# 16x2 LCD Display on RPi via I2C/SPI Backpack

Tags: display, i2c

I have bought the following two items:

- [16x2 Basic LCD](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/16-x-2-lcd-screen)
- [Adafruit I2C / SPI character LCD backpack](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/adafruit-i2c-spi-character-lcd-backpack)

which I have soldered together and got working nicely on my Arduino Uno, however, I have had less luck with the RPi.  I have been following the [Adafruit guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/i2c-spi-lcd-backpack) for the BackPack and the [RPi](https://learn.adafruit.com/led-backpack-displays-on-raspberry-pi-and-beaglebone-black/overview) but this is focused on other types of display.  I've also looked at the [Raspberry Pi Spy](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/11/enabling-the-i2c-interface-on-the-raspberry-pi/) posts but these focus on doing it without the backpack.

My Question:  Has anyone had any success with what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure python modules python-smbus and i2c-tools are installed.

Try checking that /etc/modules file contains the i2c related kernel modules (i2c-bcm2708 & i2c-dev)

Also check the bus you are using. Adafruits i2c use default bus but it may differ in some cases so try to edit Adafruit_CharLCDPlate class and replace the busnum parameter at line 425 with the one you are using. To check your bus use command: sudo i2cdetect -y 1 (bus format is like 0x00) (For old Rasp. Pi Model B 256MB command is sudo i2cdetect -y 0)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I have had that working, using a 2 line and a 4 line LCD display.

I don't have a write-up available yet, the Raspberry Pi Spy article explains how to configure I2C and I have some source code on github (for the 4 line version) https://github.com/penguintutor/learnelectronics/tree/master/quiz

Comment: Hi Stewart,  Thanks for replying.   I had a quick look at your code but these do not appear to use the backpack, which I had hoped to use.    I have another LCD on order so will try the 'native' approach when it arrives.